# How to change 6.1 Documents and Media Display view like 6.0.6

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have installed Liferay 6.1 in my personal site.
But i need Documents and Media Display view same as  Liferay 6.0.6 not like 6.1 format ,Because when i click Liferay 6.1 documents at Documents and Media Display it is drive to another details page, i need to download documents when i click documents (same as 6.0.6)

How to change 6.1 Documents and Media Display view like 6.0.6 .

Comment: If you want to be able to download a document by clicking the name, then you'll need to hook that functionality into that portlet. I haven't used any versions prior to 6.2, but I have had to hook similar scenarios (search results) to achieve the same functionality. You could also consider other means of displaying documents for download purposes, such as Asset Publisher with a custom Display template.

Comment: @Origineil would you mind converting your comment as an answer?

Comment: Thank you. which JSP files need to add Hooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, in order to "override" the out-of-the-box functionality of Liferay portlets you will need to hook the respective JSP pages.

The Document Display renders [file entries](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/document_library_display/view_file_entries.jspf) in a search container with `rowHREF`(line 111) controlling the navigation to the [details page](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/document_library/view_file_entry.jsp). The download URL (line 473) within that page doesn't appear to use anything that you wouldn't have access too "higher" up.

So, you should be able to do something similar to the following in place of the if/else.

```
rowHREF = DLUtil.getPreviewURL(fileEntry , fileEntry.getLatestFileVersion(), themeDisplay, StringPool.BLANK);
```

Of course, this assumes you'll always want the latest version of the file. If you want to provide the ability to download "archived" versions, then I would suggest leaving the details navigation in place and consider alternative means by which to provide download functionality. For example, we use Category Navigation + Asset Publisher with a custom Display Template to allow a browsable/filterable alternative to directly exposing Documents and Media Display as we wanted to restrict that portlet's scope of use to admin-only.